# firebase functions - detect head requests

Tags: firebase, curl, google-cloud-functions

I have some firebase cloud functions set up like this:

```
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('404'));
app.head('/:userId/:slug', trackFile);
app.get('/:userId/:slug', trackFile);

app.use('/api', app);
export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

As you can see I have defined a route for `HEAD` requests, but in the `trackFile` function, I am writing the request method (`req.method`) to firestore, and it's always coming back as 'GET'.

I am testing it with curl to make the head request: `curl -I https://myfirebaseapp.com/etc/etc/`

Is there some gotcha with firebase functions where it always passes HEAD requests to GET routes? I need to know when a request is a HEAD request to properly track it.

**Update**: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/351) in the firebase function github repo.

Comment: I have also tried `app.all()`

Answer (score 0):

This is standard Express behavior, as detailed here: https://github.com/expressjs/expressjs.com/issues/748

Comment: That issue was resolved with this merge that amends the docs to say `app.get()` only gets called if no `app.head()` for the same path exists. Note I have a head route defined. https://github.com/expressjs/expressjs.com/pull/750/files#diff-5e49666b0c6bf9d2eef8c80d3842b3b3R56

Comment: My reading of the comments on the issue is slightly different.  It looks like you not only need to add a route, but to define a handler for HEAD requests, and you need to do so before your GET handler for the same route.  Either that, or it will pass HEAD requests to your GET handler, where you can hopefully check the request method and return a bodiless response.

Comment: which i did - they both go to the same method and it's always 'GET', as i mentioned. Even when I replace both app.get and app.head with app.all